# How to zoom in/out in Matlab editor?

Tags: matlab, editor, zooming

I am wondering if there is a way to zoom in/out or change font size or any way to make the text in the code in Matlab editor bigger/smaller!

Comment: A shortcut would be very helpful, too! Unfortunately one can not define a shortcut for it. Every time I switch from Laptop screen to Desktop screen I have to open the preferences.

Comment: In principle you should be able to define a shortcut for `zoom in` (MATLAB > Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > zoom in), however, in various Matlab version (latest for me 2022a on MacOS laptop) the shortcut does not function as expected for the help browser. As a consequence you often end up with unreadably small script. This issue is known to MathWorks since years.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You go to `Home->Preferences->MATLAB->Fonts` and you can change the size of the text. If you play with the preferences around you may be able to personalize more things also.

Comment: Thanks Ander, that's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your MATLAB version, open the "Preferences" window. At least in newer versions, this is usually found at the top of the main window, in the bar labelled "Environment".

In the window that opens up, navigate to the tab called "Fonts". At the top of the right hand side of the window, you will find a drop-down menu containing the font size. This affects the font size in the command window, editor, and the command history. You may also change the font here.

Answer (score 3):

If someone else is lead to this questions by a search engine post 2017[*](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/317240-matlab-with-hidpi-is-still-an-issue-on-linux#answer_284556): the following code apparently zooms into the whole MATLAB editor by a factor of 1.5 but requires a MATLAB restart:

```matlab
s = settings; 
currentZoom = s.matlab.desktop.DisplayScaleFactor.ActiveValue;
s.matlab.desktop.DisplayScaleFactor.PersonalValue = currentZoom * 1.5
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the other solutions work for the live editor. Instead, hold command and scroll to zoom in / out.

Comment: This also works in MacOS MATLAB R2023a.  I did it by accident.  I came looking for this answer to find out how to undo it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `View---->Zoom In\out`. It was the only way I could undo zooming in